# set default option for jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, preferences

I have a JComboBox. It contains a list of files through which I can open any file in JscrollPane.I want to add a default checkbox option such that when the user selects that option it sets it as the default file which will open when everytime I open my GUI.

```
opener.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
        box.removeItemListener(il);

        if(ev.getStateChange()== ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            File selectedFile = (File) opener.getSelectedItem();
            if(selectedFile.getName().endsWith(".png") || selectedFile.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(selectedFile);
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Could not create file", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
//Some more code

}});
```

Comment: Use a properties file. When the check box is checked get the selected combo box value and write to a properties file. And, when the GUI (window or dialog) is opened read from the properties file and set the combo box selected value.

Comment: You can use Javas preference API to store the file name.
See this tutorial for example : https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/simple-java-preferences-api-example.
But I don't understand where the default checkbox is.